# Why are split-lines saved in the attribute table? (QGIS 1.7.4)

Tags: qgis, features, splitting

A few months ago I splitted some lines in a shapefile with official roads because they are not accessible anymore. Now I loaded that file again into my project and the splitlines appears. Because I didn't made a legend yet, they show up. (see the picture below)

[image]

edited: I first selected the layer and turned on the toggle editing. Then I activated split features [image]. I drew a line across the point where the road had to be split. After doing all the splitting, I turned off the toggle editing mode.

Is it normal that splitlines are saved in the attributetable? Can this be avoided? Because it is messing up my data.

Comment: That doesn't seem right.  The split tool uses a disposable line object and when the tool is deactivated, or the cut is made, the line is destroyed.

Comment: Can you describe the process that you used to do the splitting.

Comment: I added the description to my question